# List item issue when certain screen size

Tags: html, css

I've been fighting with the whole day and it's probably something so simple but need a push in the right direction.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Xl6.png

How can I fix this? The HTML is a basic unordered list with list items and anchors. I set the icons as a background image.

This is the CSS:

```
.cd-bouncy-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 48%;
  top: 50vh;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100vh);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100vh);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100vh);
  -o-transform: translateY(100vh);
  transform: translateY(100vh);
  text-align: center;
}
.cd-bouncy-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 90px 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: default !important;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;

}

.cd-bouncy-nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cd-bouncy-nav a::before {
  /* icons */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #bcaf96;
  /*background-image: url("../img/cd-category-icons.svg");*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../img/browser.svg");
  /*background-position: 0 0;*/
  background-position: 20px 20px;
}
.no-touch .cd-bouncy-nav a:hover::before {
  background-color: #DC965A;
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li:nth-of-type(2) a::before {
  /*background-position: -80px 0;*/
  background-image: url("../img/mobile.svg");
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li:nth-of-type(3) a::before {
  /*background-position: -160px 0;*/
  background-image: url("../img/diamond.svg");
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li:nth-of-type(4) a::before {
  /*background-position: -240px 0;*/
  background-image: url("../img/pulse.svg");
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li:nth-of-type(5) a::before {
  /*background-position: -320px 0;*/
  background-image: url("../img/planet.svg");
}
.cd-bouncy-nav li:nth-of-type(6) a::before {
  /*background-position: -400px 0;*/
  background-image: url("../img/lab.svg");
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-bouncy-nav {
    max-width: 450px;
  }
  .cd-bouncy-nav li {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
  }

}
```

Comment: _"How can I fix this? "_ You didn't tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: Please post the HTML as well. Preferably a demo would be nice. I guess you want to fix the misalignment of the penultimate item.

Comment: Add your HTML code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a smaller screen size, the text content of the 3rd list item exceeds and pushes the below item. You can set a fixed height to deal with the problem.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .cd-bouncy-nav li {
    height: 175px; /* Add */
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]